# What is an example of a hyperbolic triangle with less than pi angle sum?

Tags: geometry

I have read this is true for all hyperbolic triangles, but I am trying to find an extreme example, or a limit behavior, were the sum of the angels of a hyperbolic triangle are minimized.  Is there a min/ inf?  Also, why do all hyperbolic triangles have angles sum less than pi (if that is true)?

To avoid ambiguity, I am referring to hyperbolic triangles in the open upper half complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

[The area of the triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle) is $\pi$ minus the sum of its angles hence the infimum of the sum of the angles is zero, when the triangle gets larger and larger.